# Using jQuery to check if a link is internal or external

Tags: jquery

I want to write a script which can determine whether a link is internal or external. This is simple from my perspective, all internal links are relative, so they start with a /. All external links start with an http:// - all good so far. However I can't figure out how to do a ':contains()' on anything other than text - how can a search for a string within an attribute?

Once I can do this I'm happy to add target _blank myself, unless you know a better way to do it

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You could use the [`attribute^=value`](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/attributeStartsWith#attributevalue) syntax to find hrefs that start with `http` or `/`:

```
$("a[href^='http']") // external
 
$("a[href^='/']") // internal
```

---

Here's a better solution: You can add `$('a:external')` and `$('a:internal')` selectors to jQuery with the plugin code below. Any URL that begins `http://`, `https://`, or `whatever://` or `//` is considered external. All other URLs are considered internal.

```
    $.expr[':'].external = function (a) {
        var PATTERN_FOR_EXTERNAL_URLS = /^(\w+:)?\/\//;
        var href = $(a).attr('href');
        return href !== undefined && href.search(PATTERN_FOR_EXTERNAL_URLS) !== -1;
    };

    $.expr[':'].internal = function (a) {
        return $(a).attr('href') !== undefined && !$.expr[':'].external(a);
    };
```

Comment: Am I right in saying that an internal url won't always begin with a forward slash. it might be better to use $('a[href!=http:] a[href!=https:]') for internal.

Comment: For what I was doing the attribute selectors were the better option. However, there is a slight issue with them. They should be $('a[href^="http"]') and $('a[href^="/"]')

Comment: This would fail with a protocol-relative URL, such as `//www.google.com`.

Comment: You can fix it with `/^(\w+:)?\/\//`

Comment: wrong answer. Fails at links starting with // and internal links starting with page name, not with /

Answer (score 10):

I'm using WordPress for my CMS, and so most (if not all) of my internal links start with "http". I found a pretty interesting solution here: http://www.focal55.com/blog/jquery-tutorial-add-class-all-outbound-links-your-site

In case that site is down, it basically boils down to this selector (I modified it a bit):

```
$( 'a[href^="//"],a[href^="http"]' )
    .not( '[href*="' + window.location.hostname + '"]' )
;
```

Note that this selector will [not be the fastest](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) according to the jQuery docs.

Comment: Glad to hear it. Keep in mind that there may be some edge cases where this will miss external links. Something like external.com/?ref=internal.com will probably trip it up. I haven't run into anything like that in my usage yet, but it could be good to know.

Answer (score 3):

Select only anchors that point back to your domain when the href is the **FULL URL**.

```
jQuery("a:not([href^='http://']), " +
        "a[href^='http://localhost.com'], " +
        "a:not([href^='http://localhost.com/wp-admin'])").addClass("internal");
```

Answer (score 3):

I prefer this selector myself, it protects against false positives for absolute links that point to your site (like those often generated by a CMS system).

```
var currentDomain = document.location.protocol + '//' + document.location.hostname;
var outboundLinks = 'a[href^="http"]:not([href*="' + currentDomain + '"])';
```

Here's the use case where this worked for me, for context:

```
var currentDomain = document.location.protocol + '//' + document.location.hostname;
$('a[href^="http"]:not([href*="' + currentDomain + '"])').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    // track GA event for outbound links
    if (typeof _gaq == "undefined")
        return;

    _gaq.push(["_trackEvent", "outbound", this.href, document.location.pathname + document.location.search]);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I use this one to find all urls pointing to `domain other than current domain` or one  with (html5 deprecated) `attribute target="_blank"`

```
var contrastExternalLinks =  function() {
    //create a custom external selector for finding external links
    $.expr[':'].external = function( obj ) {
        return (
            $(obj).attr('target')   &&  $(obj).attr('target') =='_blank' ) 
                || 
                    (!obj.href.match(/^mailto\:/)   && !obj.href.match(/^tel\:/)    &&  (obj.hostname != location.hostname )
                        );
    };
    // Usage:
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('a:external').addClass('external');///css('background-color', 'green');   
    })



}();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready( function() {
$('a[href^="http"]').not('a[href^="http://' + $(location).attr('hostname') + 
'"]').attr('target', '_blank');
});
```

Replace "http" with "https" if you need to

Answer (score 0):

I think the simple and less headaches approach for this is not to use pure javascript or jQuery, but combine it with html instead and then check if the clicked link containing your base site's url. It will work for any type of base url (eg.: example.com, example.com/site). If you need for dynamic value, then you just need to set the value using your preferred server side programming language, such as PHP, asp, java etc.

Here is an example:

**HTML**

```
<!--Create a hidden input containing your base site's url.-->
<input type="hidden" id="sitedomain" value="example.com/site"/>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(".elem").on("click", function(e){
  if($(this).closest("a").length) {
  var url = $(this).attr("href");
  var sitedomain = $("#sitedomain").val();

  if(url.indexOf(sitedomain) > -1) {
    alert("Internal");
  } else {
    alert("External");
  }
 }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try it

```
var fullBaseUrl = 'https://internal-link.com/blog';

var test_link1 = 'https://internal-link.com/blog/page1';
var test_link2 = 'https://internal-link.com/shop';
var test_link3 = 'https://google.com';

test_link1.split(fullBaseUrl)[0] == ''; // True
test_link2.split(fullBaseUrl)[0] == ''; // False
test_link3.split(fullBaseUrl)[0] == ''; // False
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding **how** and **why** it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.