# Test hyperlinks to see if links are going current page vs different page with jQuery / javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, location, href

Is there a way of using javascript/jquery to test if a clicked hyperlink is going to the current page (ie anchor tags) vs going to a different page.

If my current url page is http://www.mypage.com/mypage/index.html

If so, I want to ignore these instances:

```
 <a href="#">

 <a href="index.html#anchor5">

 <a href="#mytitle1">

 <a href="//www.mypage.com/mypage/index.html#anchor1">

 <a href="mailto:xxxxxxxx@gmail.com>

 <a href="tel:+12344555">
```

And also ignore other instances that I might have missed above that references the current page with a href tag.

Thanks

Comment: Check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1227631/using-jquery-to-check-if-a-link-is-internal-or-external?answertab=votes#tab-top), this is what you want using jQuery

Comment: @MatteoBasso Thanks for the article. I am looking for something that tests if the hyperlink is an anchor tag within the current vs external page.  The external page could be on the same domain or could be a different domain.